# wxPython: sizers, grids are driving me crazy

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm learning wxPython, and I'm trying to write a student information manager. I've been writing CLI programs for many years, so I don't have much experience making GUIs.

First, I drew a blueprint for my UI.
[image: A blueprint of my UI]

Then, I tried to make it in wxPython but the sizers are really driving me crazy. I never used any kind of sizer before! (Visual Basic was the first language I learned ^__^)

Finally, I wrote this codes:

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sheet


class Sheet(sheet.CSheet):
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col):
        sheet.CSheet.__init__(self, parent)
        self.row = self.col = 0
        self.SetNumberRows(row)
        self.SetNumberCols(col)

        for i in range(row):
            self.SetRowSize(i, 20)


class ChartPanel(wx.Panel):
    '''This is the panel for the chart, but the still working on it. '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        # However, just put the chart into main frame.
        chart = ChartPanel(self)
        chart.SetBackgroundColour("blue")

        Students = Sheet(self, 5, 2)
        History = Sheet(self, 2, 2)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #1")
        button2 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #2")
        button3 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #3")

        sizer.Add(Students, pos=(0, 0), span=(5, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(History, pos=(0, 2), span=(2, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(chart, pos=(2, 2), span=(3, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        sizer.Add(button1, pos=(5, 0), span=(1, 1))
        sizer.Add(button2, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 1))
        sizer.Add(button3, pos=(5, 2), span=(1, 1))

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(5)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="BoxSizer Example")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But this program is ugly and buggy. Can someone please teach me how to use the sizers in a smart way, and help me to modify my code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know how you feel, so first now many many people understand your utter frustration... to understand sizers I tried to read many documents about sizers but I finally got it by thinking of it like CSS in HTML, so read this http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/margins/ AND the page after it, I find it to explain CSS really well and it is the same layout model as sizers.... I can't believe I remember that link been a while sense I read it guess it shows it is good marketing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I had to remove your `AddGrowableColumn()` and `AddGrowableRow()` lines because they gave me errors. I read the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FlexGridSizer-class.html#AddGrowableRow) for those functions and I don't think you want to call them (but only you know how you want your UI to look).

You actually seem to have a pretty good grasp on sizers. The problem is that `MainPanel` doesn't know the size of `MainFrame`, so part of your UI is cut off. Fixing this problem is pretty easy and you have two options.

**Option 1**
In `MainFrame.__init__()`, place `panel` inside a sizer. This will allow the sizer to set the size of `panel` based on the size of `MainFrame`. Right now there is no connection between their sizes. The change will look like this:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="BoxSizer Example")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer) #this allows panel and MainFrame to influence each other's sizes
        self.Show()
        self.Fit()
```

**Option 2**
`MainFrame` only has 1 object in it, a `MainPanel`. So why not combine those two classes into one? Simply add all your code from the `MainPane1` into `MainFrame` then delete `MainPanel`. The important part is that `MainPanel.__init__()` calls `SetSizer()`. If you move that code into `MainFrame.__init__()` then you're still doing exactly what I suggested in Option 1 but you have one less class. That would look like this:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="BoxSizer Example")
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        # However, just put the chart into main frame.
        chart = ChartPanel(self)
        chart.SetBackgroundColour("blue")

        Students = Sheet(self, 5, 2)
        History = Sheet(self, 2, 2)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #1")
        button2 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #2")
        button3 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #3")

        sizer.Add(Students, pos=(0, 0), span=(5, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(History, pos=(0, 2), span=(2, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(chart, pos=(2, 2), span=(3, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        sizer.Add(button1, pos=(5, 0), span=(1, 1))
        sizer.Add(button2, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 1))
        sizer.Add(button3, pos=(5, 2), span=(1, 1))

        #I removed these lines because they gave me errors and I don't understand why you needed them
        #sizer.AddGrowableCol(5) 
        #sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Show()
```

Finally, I don't like using `wx.GridBagSizer`. I prefer to use nested `wx.BoxSizer` objects. I find I get more control and it allows me to visualize what my UI will look like from just the code because I'm breaking the UI into smaller chunks. However, **this is a matter of personal preference and you should use whatever method you understand and are comfortable with**. Looking at your blueprint, I see that there are two columns. So first we need a sizer to deal with those columns. Then, each column can be broken into two rows. And the buttons need one more sizer to hold them.. The code would look like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) #this will make the columns

    rightSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #this will be the rows on the right
    # However, just put the chart into main frame.
    chart = ChartPanel(self)
    chart.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
    History = Sheet(self, 2, 2)

    rightSizer.Add(History, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    rightSizer.Add(chart, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    leftSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #this will be the rows on the left
    Students = Sheet(self, 5, 2)

    buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) #this will organize the buttons
    button1 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #1")
    button2 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #2")
    button3 = wx.Button(self, label="Button #3")

    buttonSizer.Add(button1)
    buttonSizer.Add(button2)
    buttonSizer.Add(button3)

    leftSizer.Add(Students, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    leftSizer.Add(buttonSizer)

    mainSizer.Add(leftSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    mainSizer.Add(rightSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
    self.Fit()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still have two problem: 1. I want the widget change thier size when user resized window. 2. Three button in the frame uses too much space, I want they are look simlar as my blueprint.

Comment: Then you need to make the buttons smaller. You'll have to set the size of the buttons when you create the buttons. Other than that, the `wx.EXPAND` flags should mean that everything else resizes with the window.

Comment: Thanks. Nested sizers are really useful!

Comment: @比尔盖子 They are a bit difficult when you start but once you learn how to use them Sizers are very powerful. You should also read [this tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers).

Comment: Great. I also brought *WxPython In Acton*.